# Laravel 5.7 fill data direct from database to select input

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to get direct data in master table with format `array($key => $value)` :

```
in controller:

$result = array();
$color_list = Master::whereRaw("type = 'color'")->get();

// format data for select input
foreach ($color_list as $value) {
     $result[$value->id] = $value->name;
}

return view('backend.product.create', compact('result')
```

in View:

```
{!! Form::select('color', $result) !!}
```

Purpose: *Do not use foreach to build data for the selected input*

i find a code:

```
$color_list = Master::lists('id', 'name');
```

but it not work on Laravel 5.7

Can anyone please help?

Comment: use `Master::whereRaw("type = 'color'")->pluck('id', 'name')`

Comment: @Davit: it's worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
$color_list = Master::whereRaw("type = 'color'")->pluck('name', 'id');
```

result must be

```
Collection {#499
  #items: array:10 [
    117 => 'master1'
    118 => 'master2'
    119 => 'master3'
    .........
  ]
}
```

or for get array use

```
$color_list = Master::whereRaw("type = 'color'")->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

result must be array

Answer (score 1):

```
$color_list = Master::whereRaw("type = 'color'")->pluck('name', 'id');
```

The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key
[Doc Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: result must be `[name => id]`

Comment: pluck( 'name', 'id')

Comment: I know it. Thanks